# Can I truncate while rounding

Tags: sql-server, rounding, sql-server-2014, truncation

In SQL Server 2014 I have some values that have trailing zeroes as well as some values after the decimal place

```
select top 25 
    ProductName, round(UnitPrice, 1) as 'Price of Products'
from 
    Products
```

This query returns the result something like this:

```
Chai                           18.00
Chang                          19.00
Aniseed Syrup                  10.00
Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning   22.00
Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix         21.40
```

My question is can I remove trailing zeroes after the decimal place while keeping any value that may be there such as the 21.40 for example while the other values just stay as 18 or 22 as round does not remove trailing zeroes

Comment: James, you are solving your problem at the wrong end. SQL Server is supposed to give *data*, not *presentation*. If you want to display `18` to the user instead of `18.00`, make changes to the component that displays the data, not to the component that delivers the data.

Comment: to answer the question, yes it can be done, but it will be messy to do in TSQL.  As @Tomalak said, best to do it on the client side.  If you absolutely cannot do that, then say so, and i'm sure we can write up the TSQL needed.  Basically, only display the cents when it is non-zero, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I would want to display the cents when it is non-zero otherwise remove any trailing zeroes.  so if it was 19.40 the cents would display but if it was 21.00 it would just display 21

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2014 has [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh213505.aspx) function.

If you round the price to 2 decimal digits, the formatting string should look like this:

```
FORMAT(ROUND(UnitPrice, 2), '0.##')
```

In fact, you don't need explicit `ROUND`, `FORMAT` would do it any way:

```
FORMAT(UnitPrice, '0.##')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack, this works assuming you will always have a decimal place.

```
create table t1 (col1 decimal (5,2));

insert into t1 (col1) values (10.00)
insert into t1 (col1) values (10.50)

select case col1 % 1
  when 0 then PARSENAME(col1, 2)
  else col1
end
from t1
```